# How to debug android app on dell inspiron 3542?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-debug

This may sound silly but I already know how to debug apps using android studio both on mobile and emulator. My problem is that  currently my mobile usb mechanism is damaged so my laptop unable to recognize it even for file transfer. and I can't use emulator even genymotion cause **dell inspiron 3542** have **4gb ram** and **4th generation i3 processor with 1.7GHZ clock speed**. Whole system hangs when I use both android studio and genymotion at the same time.

**So is there any other way like debugging using overWifi or bluetooth ?**

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use wifi adb plugin in android studio
Settings>>plugins>>browse reositories>>in search bar enter "ADB WIFI" 
and follow the instructions.

Comment: great I installed it but now I am using miui9 and unable to activate option install via usb. I tried other solutions over the internet but didn't get chinese vpn.